# Can't find <linux/alarmtimer.h> header file in linux compile system

Tags: linux-kernel, build-error

I tried to compile my new test Daemon module on Linux but I saw below compile error message.

```
test.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'linux/alarmtimer.h' file not found
==> #include <linux/alarmtimer.h>
```

`linux/header` is basic header file, right?

Why do I get this error?

Comment: What is your -I directive, or the contents of your Makefile?  Some log outputs perhaps?

Comment: I think I have to add some code to Android.mk file..

Comment: maybe, LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(QC_PROP_ROOT)/common/inc

Comment: please help me ...

Comment: I need to use linux/kernel API, Not Android Bioinic

Comment: Please show the output from your makefile/build process

Comment: Header `linux/alarmtimer.h` is the [common Linux kernel header](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/alarmtimer.h), not an Android-specific. How do you build your module?

Comment: Tsyvarev, Thank you. This is my mistake, you are right linux/alarmtimer.h is not an android-specific